# Error import library JFreeChart (java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make a java application, I need to use JFreeChart library and I impoort it but an error is displayed :

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package org.jfree.chart does not exist
>       at testJfreeChart.(testJfreeChart.java:6)

what i should do ?

Comment: Added JFreeChart's jar file to your library ?

Comment: no ! JfreeChart's jar file should i download it ?

Comment: Right click 'libraries' in the project list, then click add JAR.

Comment: Yes i do it and it works ! thanx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have your imports correct and added the library somehow to your project. Then this sounds like a dependency problem.

I would suggest using Maven as a basic tool for dependency management. It's easy to use and helps you with all the hustle you come across. I don't know what IDE you're using. But if it's Eclipse, just add a pom.xml to you project base, convert your project to a Maven Project (right-clicking -> convert -> Maven) and add the jFreeChart dependency. Maven will download the depencies and everything is done :)

Maven basic pom:
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Basics
Maven repo link:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart

Comment: In fact i use Netbeans. yes you are right I downloaded JFreeChart jar file and I added it to my libraries project and it works ! good work ! thanx